# Command \noboundary unavailable in encoding LGR (TeX Live 2017)

Tags: font-encodings, greek, pdf-a, pdfx

This problem started appearing for me in TeX Live 2017:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \noboundary unavailable in encoding LGR.
```

The file still compiles and the PDF looks as expected, except regular sigmas are replaced with word-final sigmas.[°](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Glyph_variants) Disabling the `pdfx` package suppresses the error. What is happening and why didn't it happen in TeX Live 2016?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,american]{babel}

\begin{document}

time is \foreignlanguage{greek}{κρόνος} if nothing else

\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
Θέλω νὰ πιστεύω — καὶ ἡ πίστη μου αὐτὴ βγαίνει πάντοτε πρώτη στὸν ἀγώνα της μὲ
τὴ γνώση — ὅτι, ὅπως καὶ νὰ τὸ ἐξετάσουμε, ἡ πολυαιώνια παρουσία τοῦ ἑλληνισμοῦ
πάνω στὰ δῶθε ἢ ἐκεῖθε τοῦ Αἰγαίου χώματα ἔφτασε νὰ καθιερώσει μιὰν ὀρθογραφία,
ὅπου τὸ κάθε ὠμέγα, τὸ κάθε ὕψιλον, ἡ κάθε ὀξεία, ἡ κάθε ὑπογεγραμμένη, δὲν
εἶναι παρὰ ἕνας κολπίσκος, μιὰ κατωφέρεια, μιὰ κάθετη βράχου πάνω σὲ μιὰ
καμπύλη πρύμνας πλεούμενου, κυματιστοὶ ἀμπελῶνες, ὑπέρθυρα ἐκκλησιῶν, ἀσπράκια
ἢ κοκκινάκια, ἐδῶ ἢ ἐκεῖ, ἀπὸ περιστεριῶνες καὶ γλάστρες μὲ γεράνια.
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: pdfx redefines the primitive \noboundary to be an encoding dependant command. It will now fail with all other encodings than the local pdfx-encoding L8U. Imho this is not a good idea and you should contact the author.

Comment: On the chat David wrote that the author already knows about the problem.

Comment: The easiest way to fix this is as by surrounding the loading of the  {pdfx}  package as follows.

`\let\realnoboundary\noboundary
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\let\noboundary\realnoboundary`

Comment: Then notify me if you find any others of this kind.

Comment: The same problem occurs with 
`\usepackage[unicode,arabic]{hyperref}`
replacing loading of  `pdfx`  in the example. 
This is for the same reasons.